# Пропадает Google reCAPTCHA при аякс запросе

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, recaptcha

Доброго времени суток, у меня на главной странице есть форма отправки вопроса, к ней подключена обычная **google recaptcha v2**, всё работает отлично, пока не начинаю бегать по другим страницам сайта (они все подключается без перезагрузки, аяксом подгружается контентная часть). И вот, после любого аякс запроса, рекапча на главной странице - исчезает.

Может у кого-то была подобная проблема?

Comment: ошибки из консоли покажите. Гадать по козьим какашкам мы, к сожалению, не умеем.

Comment: @Jean-Claude в том то и дело, нет никаких ошибок, ко всему прочему и консоль логом проверь то нечего. Я описал проблему максимально как мог, больше то и дать нечего, не скидывать же сюда весь огромный код.
Просто после любого аякс запроса на сервер, рекапча исчезает, без каких-либо ошибок. Страница при всём при этом не перезагружается.

Comment: что значит рекапча исчезает? ее хтмл-код пропадает из страницы?

Comment: @Jean-Claude нет, код остаётся на месте, ошибок никаких не вылетает, просто исчезает фрейм рекапчи (визуально его не видно -  height 0)

Ещё я пробовал перезагружать рекапчу после аякс запроса, но эффект не изменился. Все скрипты на месте, но рекапчу не видно у блока пропадают параметры высоты и ширины.

Comment: ну так сделайте так, чтобы не пропадали.

Comment: @Jean-Claude да, давно уже сделал )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ах, да, забыл. Собственно проблема была в том, что скрипт рекапчи подключался в хедере вместе со всеми скриптами (который статичен), а контентная часть, в которой находилась рекапча (перезагружалась аяксом).

Проблема решилась путём добавления **recaptcha/api.js'** в контентную часть.